# ¿Por qué Axios agrega la ruta local cuando realizo petición http?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios

Intento utilizar la API de cocktails, y al momento de llamarla, veo que en la petición se agrega mi ruta local. Estoy dentro de un pequeño proyecto en react-TS y no ha sido posible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que no debe tener mi dirección localhost.

- Utilizo fetch pero con axios pasa igual.

```
  const fetchCocktailByName = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita"
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setCocktails(data.drinks);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchInput) {
      fetchCocktailByName();
    }
  }, [searchInput]);
```

¿Qué podría ser?

Comment: Pon http:// o el https:// según corresponda

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tanto axios como fetch están tomando como que es una ruta relativa, para evitar esto simplemente agrega http:// o https:// (según corresponda) a tu url, es decir: `https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita`

De esta manera no te agregará tu ruta.